# AngularJS - accessing a array of objects in a controller goes wrong

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to access an array of objects in my controller :

```
angular.module('schoolManagement').controller('CycleController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.cycles = [
        {
            nomCycle : 'Primaire',
            active   : 'oui'
        },
        {
            nomCycle : 'Collège',
            active   : 'non'
        }
    ];
    console.log($scope.cycles[0].nomCycle);
}]);
```

The ***console.log()*** gives exactly what i'm looking for the in console, but when i use ng-repeat to loop over the array in my view, it doesn't work :

```
<tbody ng-controller="CycleController as CycleCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="cycle in CycleCtrl.cycles">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>{{cycle.nomCycle}}</td>
        <td>{{cycle.active}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**EDIT :** 
Since i'm using `$scope` there is no need to use the controller syntax, the correct form in this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="cycle in cycles">...</tr>
```

Comment: You are using controller alias syntax and trying to get property from controller instance when it is assigned to scope property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that line

```
<tr ng-repeat="cycle in CycleCtrl.cycles">
```

Shall be

```
<tr ng-repeat="cycle in cycles">
```

P.S: In french, Primère is spelled : PRIMAIRE

Comment: Thank you! You're P.S. made my day, hhah, what a stupid mistake. thx mate!

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `controller as` syntax, you need to change your controller to:

```
.controller('CycleController', [function() {
  this.cycles = [{
    nomCycle: 'Primère',
    active: 'oui'
  }, {
    nomCycle: 'Collége',
    active: 'non'
  }];
}]);
```

You don't need the `$scope` here. You may add it again, if you need things like watchers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to qualify the array with the name of the controller, since it's in scope. Instead, just:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cycle in cycles">
```

Comment: @BOB: No problem! aorfevre posted his answer before mine. You should mark it as correct.